# Different translation based on value

Tags: angular, pipe

I am trying to make some translation in Angular on translate pipe like this

```
 {{editableLinks ? 'Shared.Edit' : 'Shared.Details' | translate}}
```

But it does not works it always simple string like translate pipe is not bind?
Any one got similar problem with translate pipe?

Comment: So you see "Shared.Edit" or "Shared.Details" instead of having those translated? Can you provide more relevant code?

Comment: editableLinks is simple TRUE or FALSE, why do you need more code?

Comment: To see what else you have configured. And how. But another question maybe: if you just put {{ 'Shared.Edit' | translate }} there, does that work?

Comment: It works if I just put {{ 'Shared.Edit' | translate }}

Comment: Okay, which exact version of angular and translate are you using?

Comment: Workaround: `editableLinks ? {{ 'Shared.Edit' | translate }} : {{ 'Shared.Details' | translate }}` If this doesn't work there's something wrong with your translations and/or configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe me or not, this should work:

```
{{(editableLinks ? 'Shared.Edit' : 'Shared.Details') | translate}}
```

Let the condition happen first and use resulting string as a translate key. Same applies when you use `async`

Comment: It seems, this is not always true. I've just written a small application testing this. If your expression is a constantly changing variable, like Math.random() > 0.5, you often get the message: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

Comment: But this is not exactly the issue with condition or translate pipe. Put such code to the *ngIf and you should get the same error.